Is the word "around" needed?
This is the line from "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3 (2023)":

Adam: I am the Warlock, Mum, and I am done
with being ordered around.

Is the word "around" needed?

it's a good idea to wait a day or two before accepting an answer. If you simply accept the first answer as soon as it is posted, you may discourage somebody from writing a better answer.

@JavaLatte Noted!

The Cambridge Dictionary defines order as:

If a person in authority orders someone to do something, or orders something to be done, they tell someone to do it

on the other hand, order around is a phrasal verb meaning

to tell someone what they should do in an unpleasant or forceful way, especially repeatedly

As you can see, the word around affects the meaning, turning it into something more unpleasant. When Adam says "ordered around", he is complaining both about the fact that his mother tells him what to do, and also about the way the way that she does it.
Additionally, when you use the word ordered on its own, it requires either a to-infinitive to give it the meaning "tell somebody to do something", or a noun to give it the meaning "request something"

They ordered him to leave the room.
He ordered a beefburger with fries

While it would be perfectly possible for Adam to list the things that he does not want to be told to do, it would make the sentence a lot longer... and the to-infinitive cannot be omitted for this meaning.

With a side of...?
All jokes aside, it's contextual. Since the word "ordered" can have varying
meanings within context.
"I am the Warlock, Mum, and I am done with being ordered."
...Ordered what?
The word "around" helps add that extra layer of meaning and emphasis to convey exactly what Adam's trying to say by implying that he has been ordered to do multiple tasks all about, as well as making the sentence feel full, since the phrase "ordered around" is conventional.
So no, it's not strictly required, but it helps a lot with the human flow of the sentence.

this answer is remarkably vague. "with a side of" hints at the 'request" meaning, but does not explain it at all.  You talk about "add that extra layer of meaning" but you don't say what the layer of meaning is. And "around" is required.

@javalatte I've made a few edits, is this satisfactory?
